# REST Web Service transfer data over HTTP which must be text format only

Tags: web-services, rest, http

I recently came across the REST web service implanted in Spring, and it was accepting the byte array as input. But my confusion is , REST is implemented by using HTTP protocol and HTTP transfer the data in string format only, it may be JSON , HTML , XML or simple text. Then how the byte array was transferred and accepted at server side. I am aware about the HTTP message converters spring uses to convert the input to appropriate data type but my question is basically about the HTTP data transfer not on spring implementation... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> HTTP transfer the data in string format only

As you say, it uses string **format**. Actually `String` is just an interpretation of data contained in a `byte[]`. Data is always transferred/stored in form of a `byte[]`. If you then read this data you convert it to something else like a text or maybe a picture by interpreting single `bytes` as a character or maybe a pixel. So in this case Spring simply gives you the raw data of the request.